# Center & No repeat View.BackgroundColor (Iphone)

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I put a background in my view like this:

```
    UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:picture];
```

The problem is my picture is not big enough for the screen, so it repeat many times and its also not center in the View. How can I change that?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a background image like this, then use a UIImageView, rather than the backgroundColor property of a standard view. In Interface Builder, add a UIImageView, size it to the same size as your view (adjust the struts and springs to match), give it your image, and make your view transparent.

Comment: I display image using my database so I can't give my UIImageView an image in IB, I have to give it programmatically.

Comment: Okay, no problem; still use a UIImageView, but load its image dynamically, just as you were doing with the backgroundColor

Comment: did I have to do that in ViewDidLoad? because I told you I have many elements made in IB like label, slider, textfield... and when I put the image dynamically like you said, some label and textview are cover by the UIImageView, I don't understand, becaud in the IB i'm sure that all the elements are in front of the UIImageView

Comment: Just make sure your image view is behind all of them by selecting it and then selecting "Send To Back" from the Layout menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
//view. =[UIImage imageNamed:@"15-tags.png"] ;//[UIColor redColor];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);

int iImageWid=30;
int iImageHei=30;
CGRect rcCenter=CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x+(view.frame.size.width-iImageWid)/2, view.frame.origin.y+(view.frame.size.height-iImageHei)/2, iImageWid, iImageHei);

[[UIImage imageNamed:@"15-tags.png"] drawInRect:rcCenter];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
```