# How to avoid the image resizing on custom splash screen

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-5

Hi Am creating iOS app with custom splash screen, the custom splash screen gets loaded after the iOS's default splash screen with some loading progress. i did set the default image as the background for my custom splash screen, but the custom splash screen image got reduced size at the top and bottom, please take a look at the screen shots,and please get out from this

thanks in advance.

Ios's default screen

[image]

my custom splash screen

[image]

Comment: How do you show the image - via background color or in UIImageView?

Comment: maybe try using an UIImageView as suggested here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039740/center-no-repeat-view-backgroundcolor-iphone

Comment: or could be the same issue as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401252/uiimageview-with-stretchableimagewithleftcapwidth-doesnt-stretch-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, Thanks a lot.

Finally I found a trick,

First you should hide the Status Bar during launch. By just doing this Xcode -> project Targets -> summary Tab -> Status Bar -> check the visibility.

Then, set

```
[imgsplash setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]];

imgsplash.frame = CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].origin.x,
                             [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].origin.y,
                             [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,
                             [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);

imgsplash.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |  
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | 
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

by giving [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"] let the imageNamed can choose right image.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just do `imgSplash.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;`, it's the same.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure the `autoresizingMask` does nothing since the screen's bounds never change.

Answer (score 0):

Try [explicitly detecting screen size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html) and using a specific resource for a 4-inch screen.

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
    // Present an image formatted for iPhone 5
}
else {
    // Present an image formatted for a 3.5" iPhone
}
```

Per the [top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532405/images-for-iphone-5-retina-display), iOS doesn't appear to respect resources with `-568h@2x` attached to them other than the actual launch image.

**Edit:**
It appears from the repeated image at the bottom that you might be doing `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]`. With the method above, use `[UIImage imageNamed:]`.